# Joomla Jnews Display frontend list alpabetically

Tags: php, joomla-extensions

Jnews Display list
Content: http://i204.photobucket.com/albums/bb267/kellyshl/Untitled.png

i wan to know how to make it like this:
http://i204.photobucket.com/albums/bb267/kellyshl/Untitled-2.png
(Just wan it to be sorted via the List Name)

Regards, and thanks in advance

Comment: the module is found under
administrator>component>com_jnews>classes>class.module.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In _showSubcriptionList method,

After
{

```
if ( $this->showListName ) {
            if(!$this->linear) 
                if(!$this->dropdown) 
                    $html .= '<ul class="jNewsLists">';
```

}

add the statement
{

```
usort($this->lists, array("jnews_module", "cmp"));
```

}

and in the class (jnews_module) add the function
{

```
        function cmp( $a, $b )
{ 

if(  $a->list_name ==  $b->list_name ){ return 0 ; } 

return ($a->list_name < $b->list_name) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

}